# Docker : Installing Open-JDK in Ubuntu always giving error

Tags: docker, ubuntu, java-8, dockerfile, ubuntu-16.04

I am a newbie to Docker and have referred multiple questions & posts since morning regarding this query, but not able to get a working solution. I am trying to use below Dockerfile and facing issues in building a docker image :-

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
LABEL "Maintainer"="AdityaGoel"
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python-software-properties software-properties-common
RUN apt-get install -y iputils-ping
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y vim
RUN apt-get install -y mysql-client
RUN apt-get -y install openjdk-8-jdk
```

But I am facing below errors :-

```
 => CACHED [ 2/10] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python-software-properties software-pr  0.0s
 => CACHED [ 3/10] RUN apt-get install -y iputils-ping                                              0.0s
 => ERROR [ 4/10] RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:openjdk-r/ppa                                     122.2s
------                                                                                                   
 > [ 4/10] RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:openjdk-r/ppa:                                                  
#15 2.299 gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpm_7wi8k4/secring.gpg' created                                            
#15 2.299 gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpm_7wi8k4/pubring.gpg' created                                            
#15 2.300 gpg: requesting key 86F44E2A from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
#15 31.62 Error: retrieving gpg key timed out.
#15 122.2 gpg: keyserver timed out
#15 122.2 gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c add-apt-repository -y ppa:openjdk-r/ppa]: exit code: 1
```

I have already tried following options :-

```
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
```

Another option tried :-

```
RUN echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | debconf-set-selections && add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java && apt-get update && apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer --allow-unauthenticated
```

3rd Option :- If I comment this ppa and try directly to install openjdk using `RUN apt-get -y install openjdk-8-jdk`, then I get following error :-

```
#10 132.3 Get:115 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 tcpd amd64 7.6.q-25 [23.0 kB]
#10 132.4 Fetched 73.6 MB in 2min 10s (565 kB/s)
#10 132.4 E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libs/libsm/libsm-dev_1.2.2-1_amd64.deb  Connection timed out [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
#10 132.4 
#10 132.4 E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get -y install openjdk-8-jdk]: exit code: 100
```

Any help shall be highly appreciated.

--
Thanks for any help.
aditya

##### Edit no. 1 :-

Updated Docker File looks like :

```
FROM openjdk:8
LABEL "Maintainer"="AdityaGoel"
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN apt-get install -y iputils-ping
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y vim
RUN apt-get install -y default-mysql-client
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y maven
ADD . /usr/local/docker-git-helloworld
RUN cd /usr/local/docker-git-helloworld && mvn assembly:assembly
CMD ["java", "-cp", "/usr/local/docker-git-helloworld/target/docker-git-helloworld-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar", "dockerLearn.TestFile"]
```

Now, I am getting below error :-

```
 => ERROR [8/8] RUN cd /usr/local/docker-git-helloworld && mvn assembly:assembly                    0.3s 
------                                                                                                   
 > [8/8] RUN cd /usr/local/docker-git-helloworld && mvn assembly:assembly:                               
#12 0.284 /bin/sh: 1: mvn: not found                                                                     
------                                                                                                   
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c cd /usr/local/docker-git-helloworld && mvn assembly:assembly]: exit code: 127
```

Comment: You might find it easier to start `FROM openjdk:8` rather than trying to reconstruct it yourself; you shouldn't generally install tools like `vim`, `ping`, or a Python interpreter that your application won't use.  The specific error messages suggests some network-level trouble and not a programming-related problem.  [Searching Ask Ubuntu for `retrieving gpg key timed out`](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=retrieving+gpg+key+timed+out) might give you some more tips.

Comment: What all tools do we get upon building an image from openjdk:8 ? Do I get the Ubuntu 16 in my container, upon building an image from ```openjdk:8``` ? The error message indicates that, Java has discontinued the ppa (https://github.com/shesek/spark-wallet/issues/79).

I basically want to assemble a java based project and then run the java file like this :- ```CMD ["java", "-cp", "/usr/local/helloworld/target/helloworld-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar", "TestFile"]``` Would I be able to do the same with this Build file ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that with a 3-line Dockerfile `FROM openjdk:8`, then `COPY`ing your application jar file in, then that `CMD`.

Comment: Hello David, I updated the question based upon your answer and facing a little another challenge. Your suggestions shall be appreciated.

Comment: You can use this image instead `maven:3.8.2-jdk-8-slim`

Comment: I think, it's related to setting the environment variable for maven here only.